# What is a well recognized Android Development Bootcamp?

Tags: android, kotlin, bootcamp

I have been self teaching android development with kotlin for the last year. When looking through job postings I am seeing that many jobs ask for a degree, or a bootcamp. I see that there are many bootcamps when searching them, but after researching them, many seem to be scams based on reviews. Are there any that are typically viewed as more reputable than others? Any advice would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Having just recently graduated from them, I would suggest trying Udacity (https://www.udacity.com/)
Apart from the paid courses they have also many free ones.

To me what makes them stand out is the "Ask a mentor" section. They are fast in replying and very competent.

Comment: Is this the one that you are referring to? This is the one that the android tutorials point to. https://www.udacity.com/course/android-kotlin-developer-nanodegree--nd940

Comment: Yep, that's the one I'm talking about.

Comment: Thank you, I appreciate the feedback.